# Magento 2.3 - Load product by id

Tags: magento2, product, magento2.3

I try to load a product by it's ID into my block template. Currently I am using this code which works fine:

```
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$_product = $objectManager->get('Magento\Catalog\Model\Product')->load($item->getProductId());
```

But I heard that this is not clean.
How can I improve this?

I tried it like this:

**Block:**

```
<?php

namespace Anshu\Bestsellerwidget\Block\Product\Widget;

use \Magento\Catalog\Model\ProductRepository;

class BestsellerWidget extends \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template implements \Magento\Widget\Block\BlockInterface
{
    protected $_productRepository;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\Context $context,
        ...
        ProductRepository $productRepository,
        array $data = []
    ) {
        ...
        $this->_productRepository = $productRepository;
        parent::__construct($context, $data);
    }

    public function getProductById($id)
    {
        return $this->_productRepository->getById($id);
    }

    ...
}
```

**Template**:

```
$_product = $block->getProductById($item->getProductId());
```

But I get **Type Error occurred when creating object: Anshu\Bestsellerwidget\Block\Product\Widget\BestsellerWidget**

**UPDATE**

I found this in **Magento/var/log/system.log**:

> Type Error occurred when creating object:
>   Anshu\Bestsellerwidget\Block\Product\Widget\BestsellerWidget, Argument
>   5 passed to
>   Anshu\Bestsellerwidget\Block\Product\Widget\BestsellerWidget::__construct()
>   must be an instance of Magento\Catalog\Model\ProductRepository, array
>   given, called in
>   /srv/www/vhosts/hausfux_m2/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/AbstractFactory.php on line 116 [] []

**NOTE:** Argument 5 is the line `ProductRepository $productRepository,` in the constructor

Comment: Did you check the types for `Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template` class `__construct()` method arguments? It may be due to argument type mismatch with parent class constructor.

Comment: I updated the question

Comment: please add an actual class without removing any code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had to delete the folder `generated/code`, then I executed `sudo -u projectuser php bin/magento setup:upgrade`. Now it works.

It can be enough to just execute the command without having to delete the folder first.

There was nothing wrong with the code, only with magento.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is because the arguments you are passing with the `parent::__construct` methods are wrong.

The parent function requires `\Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\Context` while you are passing `\Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\Context` as your context object.

Change the class with `\Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\Context` and it should resolve your issue.

Comment: No, it does still throw the same error. The block class already worked before perfectly fine it just crashes after adding the productRepository code lines.

Comment: Glad you were able to solve it by yourself.